# Next.js i18n routing not working in Docker

Tags: docker, internationalization, next.js

I'm trying to use the built-in [Next.js internationalized routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing).

I followed the steps and my code is more or less the same of the [official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/i18n-routing).
Everything works fine both in local development environment and also with a production build environment.

My application in production runs inside a Docker swarm stack, so I build a Docker image with this dockerfile definition (I already have the Next.js build)

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./.next /app/.next
COPY ./public /app/public
COPY ./node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

The command

```
npm run start
```

execute

```
next start
```

The app starts and works but when I change LANG next routing fails, it returns 404.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll also need to copy your `next.config.js` file in the Dockerfile, that's where your i18n config is.

```
COPY ./next.config.js /app/next.config.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We had to add 2 lines that said:

`COPY ./next.config.js /app/next.config.js` - 

`COPY ./next-i18next.config.js /app/next-i18next.config.js`